# PHP - performant way to remove duplicate values from a huge multidimensional indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a huge multidimensional indexed array in PHP that can potentially have tens of thousands of sub-arrays that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => James
            [1] => Daniel
            [2] => f12345
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maria
            [1] => Jameson
            [2] => f00000
        )
    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => f12345
        )
)
```

The last value of each sub-array is an ID as a string, and I want to clean up my array so that it contains only the first occurring sub-array of a given ID, deleting further arrays with the same ID (deleting the whole sub-array and not just the value). There can be many duplicate arrays with the same ID, and there can be many different IDs. The ID value always has the same key (in this example, the last i.e 2).

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => James
            [1] => Daniel
            [2] => f12345
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maria
            [1] => Jameson
            [2] => f00000
        )
)
```

What would be the fastest and most performant way to do this?

The source is a CSV file uploaded through a web form that I'm turning into an array like that: `array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));`

Comment: The most performant way would be, if possible to filter directly from the source. If you're building this array from a SQL query, you can change it to make sure you'll have distinct values

Comment: The source is a CSV file that I'm uploading through a form and then turning into array with array_map('str_getcsv', file($fileName)); Ideally I want to work through the file in memory and not to write it to disk or database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to process each record from the file as you read it and see if you already have encountered the same code.  Using

```
array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
```

in itself will read the all the file and then process each line with `str_getcsv` and then you may still have to process each line again to check for duplicates.

This code reads a line at a time using `fgetcsv()` and then checks if it has already been encountered ( using `!isset($used[$row[2]])`, using `isset()` is quicker than just adding a list of codes to an array and searching each time.) If it hasn't already been used, it adds the row to the output and flags the code as being used...

```
$used = [];
$output = [];
$input = fopen("a.csv", "r");
while($row = fgetcsv($input))   {
    if ( !isset($used[$row[2]]) ){
        $output[] = $row;
        $used[$row[2]] = 1;
    }
}
```